# Force http from dart.dev to use dio from flutterchina.club

Tags: flutter, http, dio

I have built interceptors around dio for error handling,logging and cache. I found some other packages like cached_network_image, advance_pdf_viewer use dart.dev's http client.

I want to make same requests processed from cached_network_image, advance_pdf_viewer from dio's client so that custom error messages are displayed in UI which provides uniformity.

```dart
Future<Dio> _getDio() async {
    final dio = Dio()..options.baseUrl = ApiEndPoints.base;
    dio.interceptors.addAll([
      DioCachingInterceptor(
        connectivity,
      ),
      DioAppInterceptor(),
      DioLoggingInterceptor(),
    ]);
    return dio;
  }
```

Any Ideas??

Comment: If you mean that you want to override `dart:io`'s `HttpClient`, you can do so via [`HttpOverrides`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/HttpOverrides-class.html).

Comment: Yes, but I actually want to map http.get() to Dio().get globally each time externally added packages calls. Is it possible?

Comment: If you're referring to `package:http`, then `package:http` is built on top of `dart:io`'s `HttpClient`, so you could still use `HttpOverrides`.